# How to add field to admin user

Tags: magento-1.9

How do I create a module to add a field to the administrator registry?

I have the following structure created:

```
app
    code
        local
            getResult
                LocalAdmin
                    Block
                        Permissions
                            Edit
                                Tab
                                    Main.php
                    etc
                        config.xml
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <getResult_LocalAdmin>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </getResult_LocalAdmin>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <getResult_LocalAdmin>
                <class>Mage_Core_Helper</class>                
            </getResult_LocalAdmin>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <getresult_localadmin>
                <class>getResult_LocalAdmin_Block</class>
            </getresult_localadmin>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <permissions_user_edit_tab_main>getResult_LocalAdmin_Block_Adminhtml_Permissions_User_Edit_Tab_Main</permissions_user_edit_tab_main>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>            
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Main.php:

```
<?php
class getResult_LocalAdmin_Block_Adminhtml_Permissions_User_Edit_Tab_Main
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Edit_Tab_Main
{
      protected function _prepareForm() {

        parent::_prepareForm();        
        $form = $this->getForm();

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('LDAP', array(
            'legend' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('User Info'),
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide'
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('ldap_user', 'select', array(
            'name'      => 'is_active',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('LDAP user'),
            'id'        => 'is_active',
            'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('LDAP user'),
            'class'     => 'input-select',
            'style'     => 'width: 80px',
            'options'   => array('1' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Yes'), '0' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('No')),
        )); 

        return $this;

  }

}
```

Currently this is so, nothing else happens ...

Comment: I think you need to rename your module namespace like this: `GetResult`. I believe magento requires Capital letter at the beginning of the NameSpace. Also you are missing one Folder. After `Permission` you should have **User** folder as per your class is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to rename your module namespace like this: `GetResult`. I believe Magento requires **Capital** letter at the beginning of the `NameSpace`.

Also, you are missing one Folder. After `Permission` you should have User folder as per your class is written.

```
app
    code
        local
            getResult
                LocalAdmin
                    Block
                        Permissions
                           User --> this is as per your class (Main.php)
                             Edit
                                Tab
                                    Main.php
```